# Why do I get the wrong $\Delta$ in spherical coordinates, if I calculate the square of the gradient in spherical coordinates $\Delta \neq \nabla^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems

I wanted to calculate the Laplacian operator $\Delta$ based on
$$\nabla=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r},\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta},\frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\right)$$

My calculation was:
$$\nabla \cdot \nabla=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r},\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta},\frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\right)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\\ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\\ \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\end{pmatrix} \\ = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 \theta}+\frac{1}{r^2\sin^2{\theta}}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 \phi}(i) $$

but according to sources online the $\Delta$ is given by:
$$
\Delta=\nabla^2=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}(\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial f }{\partial \theta})+\frac{1}{r^2\sin^2{\theta}}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 \phi}(ii)$$

I don't understand, why that is the case. Why ist the simple calculation in (i) wrong?

On the first glace I thought that I just need to  expand equation (i) to reach equality to equation (ii), but that is obviously not possible.

Comment: You calculate $\Delta$ incorrectly. You should first calculate $\nabla f$ and then take $\nabla \cdot$ of $\nabla f$ instead of just "squaring" each term. But even this won't get you the right answer as you've written it because $\nabla \cdot$ is not the same as $\nabla^T$ in spherical coordinates. For more on this, you'll want to study Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's just not that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Delta = \nabla\cdot\nabla$ does not mean that the Laplacian is the dot product of $\nabla$ with itself, it means $\Delta f = \nabla \cdot \nabla f$. I.e. the Laplacian is the divergence applied after the gradient, so you should take an arbitrary function and calculate its gradient and its divergence afterwards.